# Orbits of Lotka Volterra predator prey system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My question is about the system prey-predator of Volterra:

$\left\{\begin{array}{l}{x^{\prime}=a x-b x y} \\ {y^{\prime}=-c y+f x y}\end{array}\right.$

its associated vector field is defined by:  $g(x, y)=((a-b y) x,(f x-c) y)$

I want to understand how they find the orbit of that system:
$O x^{+}=\{x>0, y=0\}$,  $O y^{+}=\{x=$
$0, y>0\},$, and the origin.

My second question is how the deduced from the previous sets that the solution of the system is always in $]0,+\infty\left[^{2}\right.$

Thank you for all your justifications and explanations

Comment: You can explicitly solve for the other variable assuming one is zero, $x^{\prime}=a x$, for example, if $y=0$, so $x=Ae^{at}$. Since the positive axes are integral curves, and integral curves can not cross each other (by uniqueness of solutions), no curve starting inside the first quadrant can ever leave it.

Comment: Could you please give me more details.
I know that two orbits are always disjoint, but how did they define them explicitly as I wrote above. moreover, you start by assuming that y=0, is that 0 is that because 0 is always a solution so we can begin to solve our problem from that information

Comment: We simply guess that $y=0$ is an orbit and then confirm it by substituting it and finding the full solution. It can be guessed by looking at the vector field. When $y=0$ its second component is zero, so it is parallel to the $x$-axis.

Comment: with all my respect, is just kind of magic for me, let start from basics, the orbit of the system 
 $Y^{\prime}=F(Y)$ is defined by the set $$
\mathcal{O}=\{Y(t), t \in \mathbb{R}\}
$$
 so if my solution is $Y(t)= (x(t),y(t))$ the orbit is $
\mathcal{O}=\{(x(t),y(t)), t \in \mathbb{R}\}
$ so what are the folowins steps to find that $
\mathcal{O}=\mathcal{O}_{1}\cup\mathcal{O}_{2}\cup\mathcal{O}_{3}$ with 
$\mathcal{O}_{1}=\{x>0, y=0\}$, $\mathcal{O}_{2}=\{x=$
$0, y>0\}$ and $\mathcal{O}_{3}=\{(0,0)\}$ 
clear and easy :)

Comment: It's not magic at all. Just start by drawing the nullclines (as one usually does when sketching the phase portrait), and then it will be quite hard **not** to notice that the $x$ and $y$ axes are invariant under the flow.

Comment: Sorry guys, I had some lake in information about time series and phase plane so I couldn't understand your analysis, now I get the Idea that IF the two populations are inside the first quadrant, they can't ever leave. BUT I see that could happen only if the curve: $ x=0$ if $y>0$ $ y=0$ if $x>0$ is continuous on zero, which is true since that curve take the point (0,0). So what still gave me a head ake is how could this cure be continuous and at the same time the orbits $\{x>0, y=0\}$,  $=\{x=$
$0, y>0\}$, and the origin are disjoint. I hope you respond to me.

Comment: In one hand the orbits $\{x>0, y=0\}$, $\{y>0, x=0\}$ and $\{(0,0)\}$ are disjoint. In the other hand, I assume to be perfectly sure that the solutions (x(t),y(t)) are inside the first quadrant, they can't leave it, if and only if the trajectory in $\{(0,0)\}$ is "close," therefore the orbits stated previously should be disjoint !!!

Comment: The equation of trajectory on implicit form is : $$a\ln(y)-by+c\ln(x)-fx=\text{constant}$$